# Browser cache issue

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

I have varnished and Apache setup.
My Drupal 6 websites doesn't have any issue.
But in all of my Drupal 7 setup I have following issue:

Issue: Whenever I visit pages of my websites anonymously, so browser have some caches of website, and than tried to log in and visit the same pages, I get the pages as anonymous visitor, after I refresh the page by `Ctrl+F5` (`Ctrl+R`) I see the page as authenticated visitor!

if I haven't check the pages previously as anonymous user, it will not behave that way.

I don't think the problem is with the varnish, because I have the same issue when I by pass the varnish using https, or following method:

```
if (req.http.host == "example.com") {
  //let the request hit the backend, without cache processing
  return (pass);
}
```

Also I tried disabling mod_expires, but it didn't solve the issue.
I tried IE9 and Firefox browsers.

I also checked my http header using Firefox and I saw that it doesn't even reload the cached page, unless I refresh the page from top or `Ctrl+F5` and than I will get following header:

```
  Cache-Control public, max-age=21600
  Connection    Keep-Alive
  Content-Encoding  gzip
  Content-Language  en
  Content-Length    6156
  Content-Type  text/html; charset=utf-8
  Date  Fri, 01 Mar 2013 23:11:20 GMT
  Etag  &quot;1362179480-1&quot;
  Expires   Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
  Keep-Alive    timeout=5, max=98
  Last-Modified Fri, 01 Mar 2013 23:11:20 +0000
  Link  &lt;https://www.example.com/node/6&gt;; rel=&quot;shortlink&quot;,&lt;https://www.example.com/career.html&gt;; rel=&quot;canonical&quot;
  Server    Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
  Vary  Accept-Encoding
  X-Drupal-Cache    MISS
  X-Generator   Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
  X-Powered-By  PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18
```

Request Headersview source

```
  Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
  Cache-Control max-age=0
  Connection    keep-alive
  Cookie    Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=1; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; __utma=232802252.1062378112.1355538979.1362165767.1362177779.48; __utmz=232802252.1360443161.37.6.utmcsr=mail.google.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/mail/u/0/; __atuvc=3%7C5%2C7%7C6%2C2%7C7%2C43%7C8%2C68%7C9; SSESSa353b9097cd9d66db87be4c783d6cc3e=vPLzEpcgrz2iO09tStKf-962kz__q7Jkts3lASJ0JCo; SSESS77f0a3186f1d40a3c071415ed9cd209c=Bbt24kN6RuIdyhevnk_SnqXL4eDbjDWO804j-c3vcCY; has_js=1; __utmb=232802252.35.10.1362177779; __utmc=232802252
  DNT   1
  Host  www.example.com
  If-Modified-Since Fri, 01 Mar 2013 23:10:38 +0000
  If-None-Match &quot;1362179438-1&quot;
  Referer   https://www.example.com/solutions.html
  User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
```

I find out that the problem is with varnish installation, by removing following line from setting.php it has been solved ! Don't forget to restart varnish after making changes in Setting.php!

```
  $conf['omit_vary_cookie'] = True;
```

Comment: Are you using Secure Pages or Secure Login?  I have experienced the problems you're describing due to configuration issues with those modules.

Comment: No, I don't use any of those modules, and I see the same issue in all of my drupal 7 websites. Did you solve the issue, if yes what was causing it? and How?

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91353