# Varnish/Drupal caching for logged in users

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

**Problem**

Varnish is caching pages when I go onto my website anonymously.

I have "Cache Pages for anonymous users" turned on so this is expected.

But when I login it continues to load the cached page for the pages I visited when I was logged out, so the user specific menu never shows and the login button continues to show even though I'm logged in.

I though Varnish didn't work for logged in users and I'm using the default drupal caching system which I thought didn't work for logged in users? How can I prevent this?

**Server Set-Up**

LEMP Stack - Ubuntu Server 12.04

APC + Memcached

Varnish

**Drupal Caching Settings:**

Cache pages for anonymous users -> enabled

Minimum cache lifetime -> 0

Expiration of cached pages -> 6 hours

**Varnish Module Settings:**

Varnish cache clearing: Drupal default

I installed Varnish using this guide and this Varnish config file: http://andrewdunkle.com/how-install-varnish-drupal-7

**Browser Caching**

I disabled browser caching in Firefox and I still get Varnish cache hits on my homepage however now the menu loads correctly. What does this imply?

Comment: For debugging purposes, please disable caching in your browser. You find this option in the developer tools of most browsers.

Comment: @znerol Ok all done and that causes it to work as expected. What does that imply? Presumably I need to tell the browser to clear it's cache when a user logs in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

**Solution 1: Disallow caching in the browser**

In order to prevent a browser from storing and reusing a page, you have to make sure that `Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0` is on the respective (HTML) pages.

You can force this header in `sub vcl_deliver`. Just make sure that you do not put that header on static assets (like images, CSS and JavaScript files):

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  set req.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
}
```

**Solution 2: Ensure that Vary: Cookie is on the response**

If you want to force the browser to invalidate its cache whenever the cookies change (i.e. a session is opened), you have to ensure that the `Vary: Cookie` header is on the response.

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (resp.http.Vary !~ "Cookie") {
    set resp.http.Vary = resp.http.Vary + ", Cookie";
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "^,\s*", "");
  }
}
```

Again, the cache is more effective if you restrict this fragment the page / filetypes which have different contents depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

Safari (at least v5 which is the last one for Windows and the one on iPad 1 and some older iPhones) has a nasty [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71509). I recommend to add the following snipped in order to deactivate the Safari browser cache:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (resp.http.X-Generator ~ "Drupal" && req.http.user-agent ~ "Safari" && req.http.user-agent !~ "Chrome") {
    set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
  }
}
```

Note: This is a little bit different from the solutions proposed in the comments of the bug report. By placing the snipped into `vcl_deliver` instead of `vcl_fetch` we avoid having to separate the bins. Also note that by matching on `X-Generator ~ "Drupal"` we avoid disabling the browser cache for static assets.

Today (November 2013) I reproduced this misbehavior on Safari 5.1.1 (Windows), 6.1 (Mac OS X 10.8 / Mountain Lion) and 7.0 (iOS 7).

Comment: Cheers, that's worked great, I used 2. Obviously many websites will have a user menu on every page which changes if you're signed in or not (so you can't restrict the fragment to a page). Is there a clever way of dealing with this problem? (Also are there any resources you'd recommended to read up on for a Varnish Drupal beginner? I'm working through the documentation but I don't understand a lot.)

Comment: @DominicWoodman: I recommend to organize a PDF copy of the Varnish Book (linked from the [documentation page](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs)) and read at least the chapter _VCL Basics_.

Comment: I think Solution 2 is a better alternative.

Comment: @DominicWoodman: Updated answer and included snipped to fix browser cache-bug on Safari 5.

Answer (score 1):

I choose to use the second option. I added the snippet to my Vanish config file:

`/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

I added it as it's own standalone snippet as opposed to putting the if function inside the already existing `sub vcl_deliver`.